# How can I get a list of eventprocessor in axon 3.1.1

Tags: cqrs, axon

I am using Axon 3.1.1 and wanted to know,
How can I get a list of eventprocessor in my configuration file,
I went through the springAmQPmessageSource file but still not sure how to exactly do it.
So that I can pass my event to appropriate eventhandler on Query side.

```
List<Consumer<List<? extends EventMessage<?>>>> eventProcessors = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

Updated
 I was retrieving message from kafka topic and wanted to wire them to specific eventhandler but since I am not able to get evenprocessors, I am not able to do that.
Can you please tell me how to do it, if I am using Axon 3.0.5

Comment: From your question Update, I'm assuming you're introducing some form of `KafkaMessageSource`, what this (https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/375) issue on the AxonFramework GitHub page refers too actually. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `SpringAmqpMessageSource`, you will not need to retrieve the list of `eventProcessors` you've shared, as Axon will automatically subscribe all the event handling components to it for you.
Subsequently, the events the Message Source receives will automatically be pushed to all the listeners in your query side.

As this is all covered as Axon infrastructure under the hood, there is no one-off way to pull them out of it for your own use (other than potentially wiring them  yourself).
Hence, you shouldn't have to do this yourself.

But, maybe I'm missing an obvious point here.
Could you elaborate a little more why you need the list of handlers in the first place?